# Jquery .css line-height not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to set the Jquery "line-height" css value for all elements beginning with "drop_". When I run the same code replacing "line-height" with "font-size" it updates correctly, but cannot get "line-height" to update. Any ideas??

```
$.each($('[id^=drop_]'), function(index, value) {
 alert($(this).css("line-height"));
 $(this).css("line-height", "3.5px");
 alert($(this).css("line-height"));
});
```

Comment: post your html codes

Comment: Simple solution will be to create a CSS class with `line-height: 3.5px` and add the class.

Comment: [How to determine a 'line-height' using Javascript (jQuery)?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1185151), [Get line-height of element without 'px'](//stackoverflow.com/q/10507296)

Comment: Works fine http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RKxGNb

Comment: please remove px from the line-height value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
jQuery.each(jQuery('[id^=drop_]'), function(index, value) {
  alert(jQuery(this).css("line-height"));
  jQuery(this).css("line-height", "35px");
  alert(jQuery(this).css("line-height"));
});
```

```css
p { line-hieght: 10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="drop_first">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
<p id="drop_second">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
<p id="drop_third">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
<p id="drop_fourth">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
<p id="drop_fifth">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

- The recommended method for defining line height is using a number
  value, referred to as a "unitless" line height. A number value can be
  any number, including a decimal-based number, as is used in the first
  code example on this page.
- Unitless line heights are recommended due to the fact that child
  elements will inherit the raw number value, rather than the computed
  value. With this, child elements can compute their line heights based
  on their computed font size, rather than inheriting an arbitrary
  value from a parent that is more likely to need overriding.

For `line-height` property value,

- Percentage, px and em values may result in poor inheritance behavior
  and should probably not be used. It is preferable to use a unitless
  number value instead (such as 1.5).
- When the value is provided as a    percentage, it is relative to the
  font size of the element itself.

Try like this,

```
$.each($('[id^=drop_]'), function(index, value) {
 alert($(this).css("line-height"));
 $(this).css("line-height", "3.5");
 alert($(this).css("line-height"));
});
```

**Note:**
When we provide the value as a unitless number that would be multiplied by the element's font-size to calculate the line box height.

[Reference](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-height/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.div > p').css('line-height', '3.5px');
```

Please post your HTML. Or change the `.div > p` part accordingly. This should work just fine.

What you have, also works fine for me. If it does not work for you, try updating  it with my code.